# save switch button state in expandable listview

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-listview, expandablelistview

Scenario:
I have an expandable listview where in each childview I have switch button.
When there is a change in the switch state a bacground job is done in the background using Thread.

Current implementation:
I have my main fragment class and adapter which extends baseexpandable adapter.

in the adapter there is a listener to the switch which call to a method in the fragment class which executes the background operation.

One of the parametres that are trasnffered is the relevant object from the dataset and according to the result from the background job the object dataset is changed. (using set method).

Issue:
There are two main issues:
1.the switch state is not saved- meaning after re expanding the group it returns to the old state.
2.when I use adapter.notifydatasetchanged the UI is getting stack for approx 5 seconds and skipped frames message appear in logcat.

What I am looking for is a good design implementation example for the above scenarion where threads are involved.

Desired result:
1.switch button is checked 
2.background operation is done 
3.childview is updated with the new values.

Thank you all in advanced for your assistance :-)

below is part of the expandable code, it includes only the relevant parts

```
public class EXP_LST_ADAPTER extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

.
.
.
.
.
.

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View parentView =convertView;
        ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.CNTX.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(parentView==null)
        {

            parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_index_list_layout, parent, false);
            holder.g_name=(TextView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_G_Name);
            holder.g_m=(TextView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_G_M);
            holder.g_h=(TextView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_G_H);
            parentView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{

            holder=(ViewHolder)parentView.getTag();
        }

        holder.g_name.setText(S_G_PARENT.get(groupPosition).Get_G_Name());
        holder.g_m.setText(S_G_PARENT.get(groupPosition).Get_G_M());
        holder.g_h.setText(S_G_PARENT.get(groupPosition).Get_G_H());




        return parentView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView( int groupPosition,  int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        childView=convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflaterchild = (LayoutInflater)this.CNTX.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
        final int childpos=childPosition;
        final int grppos=groupPosition;

        if(childView==null)
        {

            childView = inflaterchild.inflate(R.layout.group_exp_list_child_layout, parent, false);

        }

        TextView grp_r_indx=(TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.tv_real_S_n_in_G);
        TextView grp_r_state=(TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Real_S_s);
        holder.OPR_R_S=(Switch)childView.findViewById(R.id.sw_real_dis_ena);

        grp_r_indx.setText(getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).get_s_indx());
        grp_r_state.setText(getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).getR_S_STATE_STR());
        if(getChild(groupPosition,childPosition).get_s_state()==1)
        {
            holder.OPR_R_S.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            holder.OPR_R_S.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.OPR_R_S.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                try
                {
                    if(holder.OPR_R_S.isChecked()) {

                        mS_G_frag.set_S_STATE(getChild(grppos, childpos), 1, S_G_EXP_L_ADAPTER.this);
                        /*
                        if(mS_G_frag.mSETresponse)

                            {
                                Log.i("result of switch","true");
                            }
                            */

                    }
                    else
                        mS_G_frag.set_S_STATE(getChild(grppos, childpos), 2, S_G_EXP_L_ADAPTER.this);
                    /*
                    if(mS_G_frag.mSETresponse)
                         {
                                Log.i("result of switch else","true");
                         }
                         */
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }


        });







        return childView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }



public final class  ViewHolder
{
   TextView g_name;
   TextView g_met;
   TextView g_he;
   Switch   OP_R_S;
}


}
```

mS_G_frag is an instance of the class which extends the Fragment class, the method set_S_STATE creates a new Thread and executes a bacground job. one of the paramets that are places in the set_S_STATE method is the dateset object of the child view that is being updated according to the background job response.

if any further information is required please let me know

I hope that helps.

Comment: It would be useful to see some code.

Comment: Hi Kristy, I have added some code which I hope will help you understand the issue better, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone, what I have end up doing is to update the dataset after the response from the background job is done and then call notifydatasetchanged.
Hope that helps.